# Append child in DOM table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using clone to add new row to the DOM table dynamically from a button click event like below mentioned. but i want to append the cloned node to a specific row position in the DOM table. i know i can do that by using "insertrow" option but  i want to use this using clone.

```
    var newNode = tblBody.rows[1].cloneNode(true); 
    tblBody.appendChild(newNode);
```

is there any way to insert or append the "newNode" in a position i dynamically choose rather appending it as last row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.insertBefore()` from `tblBody`, and pass the `newNode` as teh first argument, and the child of `tblBody` before which the node should be inserted as the second argument.

```
    // put this node----v  before this----v
tblBody.insertBefore(newNode, tblBody.rows[i]);
```

---

If `tblBody.rows[i]` is `null` or `undefined`, then `.insertBefore()` will just behave like `.appendChild()`, and put it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

node.insertBefore() is what you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore